# updating a document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, i have a collection and a model for that collection, let's call it Post.
I want to create an ordering mechanism, as you can see in the code.

```
var assignOrder = function(callback){
    var donePosts = 0;
    Post.find().sort({publishDate: 1}).exec(function(err, posts){
        for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){
            var post = posts[i];
            var previousPost = posts[i-1] || {};
            var nextPost = posts[i+1] || {};

            post.previousPost = previousPost.slug;
            post.nextPost = nextPost.slug;

            post.update(function(err, post, affected){
                if(++donePosts === posts.length){
                    callback();
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

I don't understand why the posts aren't updated in the database.
I get the error: error: [MongoError: Mod on _id not allowed] but i'm not setting a new _id anywhere.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `save` instead of `update` to commit changes to a model instance.

```
var assignOrder = function(callback){
    var donePosts = 0;
    Post.find().sort({publishDate: 1}).exec(function(err, posts){
        for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){
            var post = posts[i];
            var previousPost = posts[i-1] || {};
            var nextPost = posts[i+1] || {};

            post.previousPost = previousPost.slug;
            post.nextPost = nextPost.slug;

            // Call save here, not update.
            post.save(function(err, post, affected){
                if(++donePosts === posts.length){
                    callback();
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: now i get a different error: { message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "the_html_structure" at path "nextPost"'